# Why did I get an empty list using Scrapy shell?

Tags: python, web, web-scraping, scrapy

The website is "https://www.jbhifi.com.au/collections/laptops". I'm trying to crawl the href for the "next page".

[image: Area I'm trying to crawl]

But why scrapy shell returns an empty list? I'm using the statement:

```py
response.css("li.ais-pagination--item ais-pagination--item__next a").xpath("@href")
```

Please show me how to scrape this using Scrapy. I suspect this is because the class starts with "ais" (but don't know why it causes the problem). This happened to me in the past. Any solutions? Cheers!

Comment: Why don't you modify URL to get to next page ?

Comment: I'm trying to use scrapy to scrape the entire jb hi-fi. Modifying URL would not work for a different category (I'm in the computer category). I'm trying to automate everything.

Comment: It would work... by considering all the categories (but painful). And if Jbhifi changes the category name in the future (it will be more pain debugging). Retail shops like Jb hi-fi do change their category a lot.

Comment: next page href does not exists in page source

Comment: If you have problem with categories, you can automate that part and find out which category you are in by `response.xpath('//meta[@property="og:url"]/@content').get()
` and just modify the pagination related part of URL

Comment: ```
In [8]: response.xpath('//*[@id="collection-search-pager"]').get()              
Out[8]: '<div id="collection-search-pager"></div>'```
next page href does not exists in page source

Comment: In my image (the right blue circle) have the required href. I just want the XPath, CSS or in conjunction with XPath and CSS to retrieve it.

Answer (score 0):

There is a need to understand that if you are extracting selectors merely on basis of inspect element it does not work that way. You need to check page source that what actually comes at time when page was loaded. While inspecting we are able to see all that content which all request against a page update. In your case there is no such class in page source `ais-pagination--item__next`. You have to track network, check which call is being hit on click of next page button and crack the logic which is being implemented.